# Number looping get row number(01,02,03)

Tags: c#

```
string[] SName = Request.Form.GetValues("Description");
string[] Email = Request.Form.GetValues("Email");
DataTable dtable = dt();
for (int i = 0; i <= SName.Length - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row1 = dtable.NewRow();
    row1["Description"] = SName[i];
    row1["Email"] = Email[i];
    DAL.DMSS insertdata = new DMSS();
    insertdata.INSERT_DATA(loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD, input, SName[i], Email[i]);
}
```

above are my code to get the data from dynamic row add.
if i have 2 rows,data i get is :

[image]

now i want to add 1 more data ,sequence number

[image]

tried this code but not working..

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= SName.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i.length <2 )
            {
               string strvalue = i.PadLeft(2, '0');
            }
            else
            {
                string strvalue = i;
            }

            DataRow row1 = dtable.NewRow();
            row1["Description"] = SName[i];
            row1["Email"] = Email[i];
            DAL.DMSS insertdata = new DMSS();
            insertdata.INSERT_DATA(loggeduser.SUBSIDIARY_CD, input, SName[i], Email[i], strvalue);
        }
```

Comment: What is exactly not working? Does it fail to save the new data or is simply not showing it back after you save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= SName.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var rowNumber = (i + 1).ToString("0#");
        }
```